# Is this controller technically nonlinear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system, linear-control

Given a nonlinear dynamical system like

$$
\begin{split}
\dot{x}_1 &= f_1(\mathbf{x}) \\
\dot{x}_2 &= f_2(\mathbf{x}) + g(\mathbf{x})u \,.
\end{split}
$$

Now assume I have a found a stabilizing nonlinear controller $u$ that contains $\dot{x}_1$ like (just an illustrative example):

$$
u = -k_1 x_1 - k_2 x_2 - f_1(\mathbf{x}) \,.
$$

Since the control law $u$ contains the nonlinear function $f_1(\mathbf{x})$, it is a nonlinear control law.

However, what happens if I can actually measure $\dot{x}_1 = f_1(\mathbf{x})$? Then it would be just a linear combination of (measured) signals, is this still (technically) considered a nonlinear controller then? Or if I estimate $\dot{x}_1$ using a numerical derivative like

$$
D(s) = \frac{s}{T s + 1}
$$

with $T$ small enough... $u$ still a nonlinear controller? Or a linear one?

Answer (score 0):

The system $A(x, u)$ is linear with respect to the controller $u$ iff it satisfies the linearity arguments:

1) $y=A(x, u) \rightarrow \alpha y= A(x, \alpha u)$ and

2) $y_1=A(x, u_1), \ y_2=A(x, u_2) \rightarrow y_1+y_2=A(x,u_1+u_2) $

Comment: I don't mean the system itself but just the controller. With using for example state feedback linearization, some nonlinear systems can be exactly rendered linear - the controller itself might be nonlinear nevertheless.

Comment: Well, you design the control law that contains a nonlinear function. The control is thus nonlinear. Then you approximate the nonlin. f-n with a linear one and the control becomes linear. There is nothing inherently linear or nonlinear in control, it depends on the way you write it.

Comment: I don't think this is linear approximation of the nonlinear controller. By making $T$ arbitrary small, the approximation error gets arbitrary small (assuming no measurement noise). Therefore, if anything, it should be a nonlinear approximation of the nonlinear controller?

Comment: You can say that you approximate (using $f(x)=\dot{x} \sim D(s)x$) or reformulate (using $\dot{x}=f(x)$) the nonlinear static control by a linear **dynamic** one. The feedback control becomes dynamic as you either use the derivative of the state or transform the state by a dynamic block.